Handling the situation: (x ~ y) == (y ~ x)
If fitting the following two models, using linear regression, produces coefficients that are essentially the same, what is the appropriate modelling technique to use?

x ~ y
y ~ x

Is an Errors-in-variables model the way to go?
Or is the situation hopeless, with both models being essentially meaningless?
Theory tells us that:
$y=\frac{cov(x, y)}{var(x)}x+ϵx$
$x=\frac{cov(x, y)}{var(y)}y+ϵy$
I have data that produces the models:

x=1.2+0.59y
y=1.2+0.64x

For this data the slope values produced by the above theory are: 0.3689927 and 0.818845, i.e., theory assumptions are not met
The data is available, and the R code for fitting the models is:
bal_mod=glm(log(Estimation) ~ log(Elapsed_Duration), data=bal, subset=(Elapsed_Duration > 0) & (Estimation > 7))

and:
bal_mod=glm(log(Elapsed_Duration) ~ log(Estimation), data=bal, subset=(Elapsed_Duration > 0) & (Estimation > 7))

The distribution of values appears to be roughly Poisson, and adding family=poisson produces a better fit, but the coefficients do not chnage much.
Both x and y are the log form of the data.
Answers to an earlier question (Very similar coefficients in two different regression models) misunderstood what was being asked.  This completely reworked question is hopefully much clearer.

Why does the fact that the coefficients are equal matter?  Why even check the "wrong" regression?  The direction depends on the variables and your model.

The authors of a paper using the data, Dynamics of retrospective timing: A big data approach, are using x ~ y, and I think that the appropriate model is y ~ x.  The two forms have very different interpretations.

You might find this answer to be of interest.  It describes in great detail what happens when we switch dependent and independent variables, and how the coefficients in the two cases are related.

Thanks for this link to some interesting discussions.  A couple of Errors-in-variables models are mentioned.  Fitting this data using Deming regression gives x=1+y. Now Deming assumes Normality, which this data is not.  But then, would the fitted model be any different from this one???

How is this question different from your previous one here: Very similar coefficients in two different regression models?

It's the same question, but expressed less clearly than this one.  The earlier question was closed before I had the opportunity to update it.

You should edit the original question. (And of course study the suggested threads first.) Then that question will be send to the Reopen queue and can be reopened. See here: What actually happens when you edit a closed question? Not 100% sure if questions closed as duplicates can be edited?

Does this answer your question? Very similar coefficients in two different regression models

The answers to the original question misunderstood what was being asked (the wording could have been better).  This question includes wording intended to make the point that I am not asking what people had previously thought I was asking.
